# Installing GooglePlayServices with NuGet gives me a Install-Package error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, google-play-services

So I'm trying to install this [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices/) into my solution and I'm having a weird error I can't seem to fix or find a solution for.

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Install-Package : Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 21.0.3.0'. 
>   You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v2.2', but the pack
>   age does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Xamarin.GooglePlayServices
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I've tried changing my target MonoAndroid version to either the latest or the earliest and it didn't seem to change anything, so I've put it back to where it was originally.

This is the error I'm getting. The problem is I either need to get this to work (because Xamarin didn't update their website so I can't download it from there and just take their .dll) OR do the bindings for Google Play Services myself which would probably be a pain in the ass.

Unless there is another way? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I have exactly the same problem and no luck, a day wasted already.

Comment: No, I haven't, been trying for the whole day and found nothing of help.

Comment: I have the same error when trying to install Android Support Library v7 AppCompat separately (which is one of the dependencies for Google Play) and getting the same error. Other dependencies install just fine so I would guess this is the problem. I am referencing another shared Android library project though which uses Android Support Library v13 so this might cause a conflict I think. I'll try from a clean project and let you know. Please post any findings, this is just killing me...

Comment: Well in all my projects I am referencing, I'm using Support.v4 and this is the one used by GooglePlayServices so I can't check for that conflict. I'll try installing AppCompat separately then.

Comment: Tried installing it on a totally new project and the same thing happened, doubt it's a conflict problem.

Comment: Same for me :( No luck with googling unfortunately, i've updated NuGet to the latest version, cleared component cache, created clean project - same error.

Comment: OK I have succeeded when instead of "Google Play Services" component I added "Google Play Services (Froyo)" from the component store. I haven't tried to run anything real yet though.

Comment: Another success - if I create a new app and do not add android manifest (i.e. set required permissions in AssemblyInfo.cs via attributes) I can add Google Play Services component without problems.

Comment: The problem is that I need to use Chromecast from the Google Play Services and I seriously doubt that it's supported in the Froyo version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 21.0.3.0 NuGet package it only contains an assembly for MonoAndroid 4.0.3 so your project will need to target that version or above before you can install it.

It looks like you are using Visual Studio so you can either go into the project options and change the targeted Android version in the project properties and change the **Compile using Android version** or edit the project file (.csproj) and change the TargetFrameworkVersion directly in the file.

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.3</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

If you need to target Android 2.2 then you could use the Xamarin.GooglePlayServicesFroyo NuGet package since that can be installed into a project that targets MonoAndroid 2.2

Comment: It doesn't help: Could not install package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices 22.0.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: wait is it 4.0.3 or 4.3?

Comment: Looks like Xamarin.GooglePlayServices requires MonoAndroid, v4.1. Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat requires MonoAndroid, v4.0.3. So if it is at least 4.1 it should work.

Comment: That's sad because putting minimum framework version to 4.1 cuts me off  6.4% customers.

Comment: For some reason, I was using the option : "Use Latest Platform (API Level 21...)" and it did not work, I switched it to target "API Level 21" and it worked. This is pretty strange. Thanks anyways though!

Comment: thanks @lcote that solution worked for me too, when nothing else did.

Answer (score 5):

The following settings work for me:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Following [this answer](http://www.henning.ms/2015/01/28/xamarin-android-you-are-trying-to-install-this-package-into-a-project-that-targets-monoandroidversionv2-2/), all you have to do is change this:[image]

to this:

[image]